# MatchedGeometryEffect isHidden not working: "Multiple inserted views"

Tags: swift, swiftui

Setup: I have a 4x4 grid of squares/tiles. The user selects a tile on the grid. If it's not in the topmost row, I want the selected tile to disappear, and for the tiles in the topmost row to take its place. For some reason, after I move the tile in topmost row, the selected tile is not hidden anymore, and this leads to the error:

> "Multiple inserted views in matched geometry group Pair<String, ID>(first: "mod", second: SwiftUI.Namespace.ID(id: 4706)) have `isSource: true`, results are undefined."

Initially 4 tiles are selected:
[image: Initially 4 tiles are selected]

On action, the tiles in the top row move down to the positions of the selected tiles:
[image: When a button is tapped the tiles in the top row move down to the positions of the selected tiles]

You can see from the shadows that the tiles are overlapping.

Here is my code for reference:

```swift
if (row != topmostRow) {
    let temp = wordArray[topmostRow][leftmostCol]

    wordArray[row][col]!.isHidden = true // hide the selected word
    if (wordArray[row][col]!.isHidden) {
        withAnimation(.linear(duration: 0.4)) {
            wordArray[row][col] = temp // topmost tiles move down to replace selected ones
        }
    }
```

And here is the code for the grid.

```swift
struct Board: View {
    @ObservedObject var dm: DataModel
    let arr: [[Word?]]
    
    @Namespace var namespace
    
    init(dm: DataModel) {
        self.dm = dm
        self.arr = dm.wordArray
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            VStack(spacing: 10) {
                ForEach(0 ..< 4) { i in
                        HStack(spacing: 10) {
                            ForEach(0 ..< 4) { j in
                                Tile(word: arr[i][j]!, dm: dm)
                                    .modifier(Shake(animatableData: CGFloat(dm.shakes[i][j] ? 1 : 0)))
                                    .opacity(arr[i][j]!.isHidden ? 0 : 1)
                                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: arr[i][j]!.word, in: namespace)
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The result is the top tile moves down, but it just goes on top of the selected tile, which should be hidden. My question is why is the selected tile not hiding after `wordArray[row][col] = temp` and how can I solve this? When I comment out that line the tiles are correctly hidden.

Comment: Please show a [mcve].

Comment: That is still not a MRE. It should be something I can directly paste into a new Xcode project and reproduce the problem. That said, I can see that you are using `opacity` to control visibility. Matched geometry effect needs the view to completely disappear to work correctly. You can surround the `Tile` with an `if arr[i][j]!.isHidden`, and in the `else` branch you can put a `Spacer` or something like that. This may or may not affect whatever the `Shake` modifier is doing though.

Comment: @Sweeper Thank you for your response! I'm still confounded about why visually the tile is still showing, as you can see from the shadow in the picture I provided. Do you have any idea about why the opacity effect goes back to 1 after I change the position of the top tile?

Comment: As the log message says, this is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `.matchedGeometryEffect` to work, there needs to be a **source** view and one or more other views which are explicitly flagged as *not* source. The non-source views are matched to the geometry of the source view, provided that:

- the same namespace is used
- the views have the same `matchedGeometryEffect` id
- there is only one source view per id.

Based on the error messages you said you were getting, it sounds like it's the last point that is going wrong. This may be because, you are not distinguishing between *source* and *non-source* views. By default, the flag `isSource` is true. It is important that the flag is set explicitly to false for non-source views.

One way to fix would be to use hidden placeholders as the sources. These can be arranged as a grid and don't ever need to move. You can then match the (visible) tiles to the placeholders. The tiles can be made to move by changing their `matchedGeometryEffect` id.

The code you provided is missing a lot of implementation detail (in particular, `DataModel`, `Word`, `Tile` and `Shake` are all missing). So to show the `matchedGeometryEffect` working, I had a go at a trimmed-down example.

The example code below uses the following structs and classes:

- `Tile` is a model of an individual tile with a single letter on it. This is implemented as an `ObservableObject`. A tile can be in one of 3 states: not selected, selected or hidden.
- `TileView` is the view of a `Tile`. The `Tile` is observed.
- `DataModel` manages the selection of tiles and performs position switching. The collection of letters used for the example are simply hard-coded.
- `ContentView` is the view that puts it all together. This is where `.matchedGeometryEffect` is being applied. The function `placeholder` delivers a hidden placeholder for a particular position.

```swift
class Tile: ObservableObject, Identifiable, Equatable {

    enum DisplayState {
        case notSelected
        case selected
        case hidden
    }

    let id: Int
    let letter: String
    var position: Int
    @Published var state: DisplayState = .notSelected

    init(id: Int, letter: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.letter = letter
        self.position = id
    }

    func reset() {
        position = id
        state = .notSelected
    }

    static func == (lhs: Tile, rhs: Tile) -> Bool {
        lhs.id == rhs.id
    }

    var isSelected: Bool {
        state == .selected
    }

    var isHidden: Bool {
        state == .hidden
    }
}

class DataModel: ObservableObject {
    private let letters: [String] = ["K", "I", "O", "F", "A", "D", "L", "N", "M", "P", "B", "G", "C", "J", "H", "E"]
    private let nTilesInRow = 4
    let tiles: [Tile]
    private var selectedTiles = [Tile]()
    @Published private var nVisibleRows: Int

    init() {
        var tiles = [Tile]()
        var n = 0
        for letter in letters {
            tiles.append(Tile(id: n, letter: letter))
            n += 1
        }
        self.tiles = tiles
        self.nVisibleRows = tiles.count / nTilesInRow
    }

    var nRows: Int {
        tiles.count / nTilesInRow
    }

    var nCols: Int {
        nTilesInRow
    }

    private var firstVisiblePosition: Int {
        (nRows - nVisibleRows) * nCols
    }

    private func isInFirstRow(position: Int) -> Bool {
        position < (firstVisiblePosition + nCols)
    }

    func switchPositionsIfReady() {
        if selectedTiles.count == nCols {
            var positionToMove = firstVisiblePosition
            for targetTile in selectedTiles {
                if let tileToMove = tiles.first(where: {
                    $0.position == positionToMove && $0.state != .hidden
                }) {
                    tileToMove.position = targetTile.position
                }
                targetTile.state = .hidden
                positionToMove += 1
            }
            selectedTiles.removeAll()
            withAnimation {
                nVisibleRows -= 1
            }
        }
    }

    func toggleSelection(tile: Tile) {
        if nVisibleRows > 1 && !isInFirstRow(position: tile.position) {
            if tile.isSelected {
                if let index = selectedTiles.firstIndex(of: tile) {
                    selectedTiles.remove(at: index)
                }
                tile.state = .notSelected
            } else {
                selectedTiles.append(tile)
                tile.state = .selected
            }
        }
    }

    func reset() {
        for tile in tiles {
            tile.reset()
        }
        selectedTiles.removeAll()
        nVisibleRows = nRows
    }
}

struct TileView: View {
    @ObservedObject var tile: Tile

    var body: some View {
        Text(tile.letter)
            .font(.title)
            .foregroundStyle(tile.isSelected ? .white : .black)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .background {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                    .fill(Color(white: tile.isSelected ? 0.4 : 0.9))
                    .shadow(radius: 4)
            }
            .opacity(tile.isHidden ? 0 : 1)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @Namespace private var namespace
    @StateObject private var dm = DataModel()

    private func placeholder(position: Int) -> some View {
        Color.clear
            .frame(width: 70, height: 70)
            .matchedGeometryEffect(id: position, in: namespace, isSource: true)
    }

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack(spacing: 16) {

                // The grid of hidden placeholders
                ForEach(0..<dm.nRows, id: \.self) { row in
                    HStack(spacing: 16) {
                        ForEach(0..<dm.nCols, id: \.self) { col in
                            placeholder(position: (row * dm.nCols) + col)
                        }
                    }
                }
                Button("Reset") {
                    withAnimation {
                        dm.reset()
                    }
                }
                .buttonStyle(.bordered)
                .padding(.top, 30)
            }
            // The visible tiles
            ForEach(dm.tiles) { tile in
                TileView(tile: tile)
                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: tile.position, in: namespace, isSource: false)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        if !tile.isHidden {
                            withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.15)) {
                                dm.toggleSelection(tile: tile)
                            } completion: {

                                // Pre iOS 17: perform as async operation instead
                                dm.switchPositionsIfReady()
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Animation]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer! Question; from my understanding, the source view is the initial state and the nonsource view is the final state. I don't understand why all the placeholders are designated as source views as they don't have anything to do with initial state. Shouldn't the source view be the tile in its initial position and the nonsource view the tile in its second position?

Comment: @hstutea The source view is the one that defines the geometry to be matched. So I would describe this as the final state. The non-source view is the one which gets the geometry applied to it, so this starts with the initial state and then moves to the final state when the conditions for a match are applied. Btw, if the answer helped then you would be welcome to upvote and/or accept it ;)

Comment: I see. I think I misunderstood matchedGeometryEffect. When I do `wordArray[topmostRow][leftmostCol] = wordArray[row][col]` (and hide the topmost row after) instead of `wordArray[row][col]!.isHidden = true`, the animation works perfectly, but I still get the isSource warning. I thought this was because the selected tiles are immediately going to the same position as the tiles in the top row, causing a conflict. Wouldn't this still cause the same problem if I used placeholders?

Comment: @hstutea Your underlying array construction is still a bit of a mystery because you never posted that part :) But it is the case that `matchedGeometryEffect` can also be used to transition from one view to another when they both have the same id and both have isSource set to true, providing only one actually exists in the view hierarchy at any particular time. Removing the top row might satisfy this, just hiding a view would not (because the view would still exist in the hierarchy, even if it was hidden).